# In PHP, if a variable does not have a value, why does isset() still return TRUE?

Tags: php, programming-languages

Here is my code:

```
<?php
   $ja = ''; 

  if(isset($ja))
   echo "cool!";

?>
```

I get a "cool!" when running this simple piece of code in my browser. I learned from php.net that

> isset — Determine if a variable is set
>   and is not NULL

Well, in my code, I did declare the variable $ja, but I didn't add any value to it, so shouldn't it be "NULL"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though '' seems like nothing, it still has a value (a NULL character at the end of the string).

`isset()` checks if the variable is set or not, which in the case (to ''), it is. You may want to set $ja to NULL first beforehand, instead of setting it to an empty string... or use `empty()` ;)

Answer (score 3):

The empty string is still a value. so you *did* give it a value which is not null - `''` is a perfectly normal string value. perhaps you want `! empty($ja)`

Answer (score 3):

Isset is used to tell whether a variable is set or not:

```
isset($notDefined) //false
$notDefined = 0;
isset($notDefined) //true
```

(Assuming that $notDefined hasn't been defined before)

To check whether the variable is empty you can use `if(empty($var))` or `if($var==0)`

Comment: PHPs empty-function is tricky - many values are regarded as "empty". Check the docs, and generally avoid it, unless you are sure it fits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You did add value to $ja - you set it to an empty string.  An empty string is not null.

What you may be confused with is that an empty string and null both evaluate to "false" in PHP when you cast it to Boolean.

PHP's documentation is fairly clear on usage of [isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: I agree with Manto. Lots of languages have nullable types and PHP is one of them. There is a lot of documentation about this feature. As an example of this, in a language that has nullable types, a boolean can be { true | false | null }.

Answer (score 0):

The isset function does determine whether or not an object has a value.  "NULL" is truly the only way to give an object a value of nothing.  $s = '' simply gives an output of nothing.  BOOL values(true/false) says that it's yes or no... 0 simply gives the object a int value of 0.

Answer (score -1):

As the name implies of the function, it checks if some variable has been set, in a sense not that it has some value, but in a sense that it has been created. I think the name could be a bit confusing so I will bring a javascript analogy. In javascript to check if the variable exists you do the following:

```
if (typeof(somevar) == "undefined")
    alert("Sorry, the variable has not been set already")
else
    alert("Congratulations, the variable has not been set")
```

So, what you are doing is that you are making a variable `$ja`, and since by doing so, the variable already exists and therefore has been set.

Hope this helps